# Authenticating (getting token) by making Http request

Tags: tls, http, web-authentication

As the topic is a bit vague I have decided to ask you guys here what do you think and what is the best practice in given scenario.

**Disclaimer:**  I am programmer, and although I know a bit about security I don't posses an in-depth knowledge of attack, security and exploit methods and opportunities in given scenario.

I am working on **connecting our system with the external system** that is going to consume and process some of data we are sending to them.

Potential problem that I see is in Auth part of making request.

They want us to create **GET request on their Api endpoint**. It is **secure (HTTPS) endpoint**, and **username and password are to be sent in body of request**  (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).
In return we are to get back token for further authentication.

I know that sending **Username and Password in Get method type would be security nightmare as URL's persist in browsers history**.

I have read about similar situation [HERE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29758/can-hackers-find-secret-tokens-passed-to-http-get-requests) and [HERE](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/29601) talking about *security through obscurity* but I am not sure if it applies here.

Why I don't think this is security issue:

- We are not authenticating using browser, rather HttpClient
- Data is sent in body of request
- Endpoint is using secure protocol (HTTPS)

What do you think ? Is this wrong approach and/or potential security risk ?

**Update:** As @stefen pointed out that:
[RFC 7231 4.3.1:](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.1)

> "A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics;
> sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing
> implementations to reject the request."

I will leave example implementation of given call.

My **HttpWrapper.cs**:

```
public static class HttpClientWrapper<T> where T : class
    {
        public static async Task<T> GetUrlEncoded(HttpClient httpClient, string url, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
        {
            T result = null;
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url) { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters) };
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith((Task<string> x) =>
            {
                if (x.IsFaulted)
                    throw x.Exception;

                result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(x.Result);
            });

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Usage of **Http wrapper** and **Http call** as so:

```
            Dictionary<string, string> urlParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            urlParams.Add("username", "Username");
            urlParams.Add("password", "Password");
            urlParams.Add("grant_type", "password");

            AuthResultViewModel outcome = await HttpClientWrapper<AuthResultViewModel>.GetUrlEncoded(httpClient, "https://some-endpoint.com/token", urlParams);
```

This works, and I get token.

Comment: The OIDC actually allows GET to request tokens. You might try setting a `Cache-Control` though it depends on the client use whether it works.

Comment: *"... create GET request ...  to be sent in body of request ..."* .- this makes no sense.  A GET request is not supposed to have a request body. See [RFC 7231 4.3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.1): *"A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics;
   sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing
   implementations to reject the request."*

Comment: I have went ahead and took a look again, and it actually says `Make a GET request to this endpoint: https://some-endpoint.com with Body type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
`And the following values in the body:
grant_type = password
username = #yourUsername
password = #yourPassword`

I will post working example in C# of Get method in body which works and fetches token just fine.